# Run Omnet++ Simulation with cmd or java

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, omnet++

I'm using OMNeT++ on windows and I want to start my simulation automatically with some java-code or with a batch-file.

Does somebody have a solution how to run simulation from batch file or sth like that?

Answer (score 1):

If you run the simulation from the IDE, it dumps out a command line into the console window that shows how to start the same simulation from the command line. The only thing you need is that the PATH must contain omnetpp/bin and omnetpp/tools/win32/bin